# python pandas csv to html UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I was trying to convert a csv data to html using Pandas.
But i was getting the below error
 UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'', 10305, 10306, 'ordinal not in range(128)')

How to resolve this issue

Comment: Please share your inputs and outputs of code

Answer (score 1):

Importing the pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I create an example csv-file, "odd_numbers.csv", containing the odd numbers from 1 to 9:

```
1,3,5,7,9
```

First convert your CSV file (here "odd_numbers.csv") into a Pandas Dataframe, "df":

```
filename      = "odd_numbers.csv"
df            = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)
```

Then use Pandas to_html function on your new dataframe, "df",
and make sure to set the "classes" argument for this function equal to "utf8":

```
HTML_file    = df.to_html(classes='utf8')
```

The HTML file, "HTML_file", will then contain the following:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe utf8">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: At df.to_html step am facing the issue of "UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'', 10305, 10306, 'ordinal not in range(128)')"

Comment: Set your 'classes' argument, inside Pandas to_html method, to 'utf8'. In the above example: HTML_file = df.to_html(classes='utf8')

Comment: When am trying to push the HTML data (df.to_html(classes='utf8') ) into a .html file still facing the same issue UnicodeEncodeError